# How to get "Project Id" to create a Direct Link?

Tags: jira

I have my project name, but not the numeric Project Id. The latter is needed to use HTML Direct Links.I'm using JIRA 5.0.1

How do I get the numeric Project Id for a given project name?

I've searched the Project Administration area, several other places, the documentation, Google, etc but still can't find a way to get that value.

Thanks.

Comment: I googled it and found out this link.

http://jira.atlassian.com/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=10420

to create JIRA issue using HTML link.
But when i created my project with some name 'ABC' , i cannot get that pid=xxxx....

just wanted to know from where can i get that pid from ?

Comment: and whenever i run that link on localhost i get this error : You have not selected a valid project to create an issue in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it from the web browser:

1. Go to the Administration page.
2. Select the Project from the menu.
3. Hover over 'Edit Project' link and check the link href (in the status bar).
   It should be something like `http://servername:8080/secure/project/EditProject!default.jspa?pid=10040`

Where pid is the id you are looking for.

For Jira 6.x:

- place the cursor on EDIT Project button and
- look at the url being redirected at bottom left of the screen

Answer (score 63):

This solution does not require admin rights:

Navigate to `https://jira.YOURDOMAIN.TLD/rest/api/2/project/PROJECTNAME` and read the `id` in the JSON response:

```
{
    "self":"https://jira.YOURDOMAIN.TLD/rest/api/2/project/PROJECTNAME",
    "id":"12345",  ☜ Project Id
    "key":"PROJECTNAME",
    "description":..
    :
}
```

Navigate to `https://jira.YOURDOMAIN.TLD/rest/api/2/project` to get a list of projects.

---

Bonus one-liners:

Get the project Id (with `cUrl` and `jq`):

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" "https://jira.YOURDOMAIN.TLD/rest/api/2/project/PROJECTNAME"|jq -r '.id'
```

(An empty answer probably means that your JIRA server requires authentication.)

List all the visible projects and their Id:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" "https://jira.YOURDOMAIN.TLD/rest/api/2/project"|jq -r '.[] | .key + " = " + .id'|sort
```

Comment: This one worked for me - I couldn't find the Admin page mentioned in the top answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't require administrative permissions for JIRA to access.

Comment: With this one (the best for me), you can found all key value for direct jira creation : _components_, _issuetype_ supported by project, etc. So good :)

Comment: Agreed, this should be the accepted answer since it doesn't require special permissions.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Thank you! Only solution I was finding was the "Edit Project" one, but I didn't have permissions to see that button. This helped.

Answer (score 3):

This solution doesn't require admin rights and shows you all of the projects the current user can view.

`https://example.com/rest/api/2/project`

Responses found here.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4972

returns a json array.

```
[
    {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/EX",
        "id": "10000",
        "key": "EX",
        "name": "Example",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10000",
            "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10000",
            "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10000",
            "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10000"
        },
        "projectCategory": {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
            "id": "10000",
            "name": "FIRST",
            "description": "First Project Category"
        }
    },
    {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ABC",
        "id": "10001",
        "key": "ABC",
        "name": "Alphabetical",
        "avatarUrls": {
            "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10001",
            "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10001",
            "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10001",
            "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10001"
        },
        "projectCategory": {
            "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
            "id": "10000",
            "name": "FIRST",
            "description": "First Project Category"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Exporting a ticket in XML reveals the project ID for me. I am not admin, so can't access the admin page. The rest/json trick didn't work for me, either. The XML of an issue has the following,

```
<project id="1234" key="test">TEST Project</project>
```

Comment: The best and easiest way to get the project_id.